# How to change text color of cmd with windows batch script every 1 second

Tags: cmd, batch-file

The color command has to do with changing color of windows command promt background/text

color 0A - where 0 is the background color and A is the text color

I want to change these color of text every 1 second in windows batch script using an array with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F witch are the color codes.

```
0 = Black       8 = Gray
1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
2 = Green       A = Light Green
3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
4 = Red         C = Light Red
5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
7 = White       F = Bright White
```

the command should be go every second like this

```
color 01
color 02
color 03
....
color 0E
color 0F
```

and for these i found some little script but im not sure how to make it work to change the color for every 1 second!

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo !array[%%i]!
```

or this

```
@echo off CLS
for /l %%a in (15,-1,1) do (
color 0A
cls
)
pause
```

or this

```
SET COUNTDOWN=15
:COUNTDOWNLOOP
IF %COUNTDOWN%==0 GOTO END
color 0A && %R1%
CLS
SET /A COUNTDOWN -=1
GOTO COUNTDOWNLOOP
:END
```

Comment: but it could be possible! who knows!

Comment: @Jay start /b cmd /k any.bat will run a batch file in the background. For example, take Mark's script, the accepted answer, place it in a batch file called cycleColors, and then run start /b cmd /k cycleColors.bat, and your screen will cycle through colors all while allowing you to do whatever else you want.

Comment: You can manipulate the terminal (cmd) with escape configurations to have individual lines or words with different color and background, see this:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/fdabcaeb8071d5c75a2d51712db24011/raw/b710612d6320df7e146508094e84b92b34c77d48/win10colors.cmd

Comment: @Diti For what prupose? there are (far) superior ways of handling color in batch files, including the capacity to change color independently across RGB colorspace to print output in a wider variety of colors, on the same line, or at a specific screen coordinates.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This should fit the bill.  Sounds like a super-annoying thing to have going on, but there you have it:

```
@echo off
set NUM=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
for %%x in (%NUM%) do ( 
    for %%y in (%NUM%) do (
        color %%x%%y
        timeout 1 >nul
    )
)
```

Comment: How to reset the color?

Comment: Just `color` by itself will reset it to defaults.

Comment: I'm just wondering, how would you do it for some fraction of a second?

Comment: You could remove the `timeout` line, so it would execute as fast as possible, but there's not a great way to sleep for a *particular* fraction of a second in batch.

Comment: There is a tiny ugly solution @godofllamas `ping` an IP adress that you know for sure does not exist on your network and use the switches `-n 1` to let the command only ping once and `-w 500` to wait for a response for 500 milliseconds. Change the 500 how you like. It sure is not a great way and creates traffic in your network but it works.

Answer (score 4):

Try this script. This can write any text on any position of screen and don't use temporary files or ".com, .exe" executables. Just make shure you have the "debug.exe" executable in windows\system or windows\system32 folders.

http://pastebin.com/bzYhfLGc

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a _er=0
set /a _n=0
set _ln=%~4
goto init


:howuse ---------------------------------------------------------------

    echo ------------------
    echo ECOL.BAT - ver 1.0
    echo ------------------
    echo Print colored text in batch script
    echo Written by BrendanLS - http://640kbworld.forum.st
    echo.
    echo Syntax:
    echo ECOL.BAT [COLOR] [X] [Y] "Insert your text"
    echo COLOR value must be a hexadecimal number
    echo.
    echo Example:
    echo ECOL.BAT F0 20 30 "The 640KB World Forum"
    echo.
    echo Enjoy ;^)
    goto quit

:error ----------------------------------------------------------------

    set /a "_er=_er | (%~1)"
    goto quit

:geth -----------------------------------------------------------------

        set return=
        set bts=%~1

:hshift ---------------------------------------------------------------

        set /a "nn = bts & 0xff"
        set return=!h%nn%!%return%
        set /a "bts = bts >> 0x8"
        if %bts% gtr 0 goto hshift
        goto quit

:init -----------------------------------------------------------------

    if "%~4"=="" call :error 0xff

    (
        set /a _cl=0x%1
        call :error !errorlevel!
        set _cl=%1
        call :error "0x!_cl! ^>^> 8"
        set /a _px=%2
        call :error !errorlevel!
        set /a _py=%3
        call :error !errorlevel!
    ) 2>nul 1>&2

    if !_er! neq 0 (
        echo.
        echo ERROR: value exception "!_er!" occurred.
        echo.
        goto howuse
    )

    set nsys=0123456789abcdef
    set /a _val=-1

        for /l %%a in (0,1,15) do (
                for /l %%b in (0,1,15) do (
                        set /a "_val += 1"
                        set byte=!nsys:~%%a,1!!nsys:~%%b,1!
                        set h!_val!=!byte!
                )
        )

    set /a cnb=0
    set /a cnl=0

:parse ----------------------------------------------------------------

    set _ch=!_ln:~%_n%,1!
    if "%_ch%"=="" goto perform

    set /a "cnb += 1"
    if %cnb% gtr 7 (
        set /a cnb=0
        set /a "cnl += 1"
    )

    set bln%cnl%=!bln%cnl%! "!_ch!" %_cl%
    set /a "_n += 1"
    goto parse

:perform --------------------------------------------------------------

    set /a "in = ((_py * 160) + (_px * 2)) & 0xffff"
    call :geth %in%
    set ntr=!return!
    set /a jmp=0xe


    @for /l %%x in (0,1,%cnl%) do (
        set bl8086%%x=eb800:!ntr! !bln%%x!
        set /a "in=!jmp! + 0x!ntr!"
        call :geth !in!
        set ntr=!return!
        set /a jmp=0x10
    )

    (
    echo.%bl80860%&echo.%bl80861%&echo.%bl80862%&echo.%bl80863%&echo.%bl80864%
    echo.q
    )|debug >nul 2>&1

:quit
```

Comment: Very nice example :D

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something very similar. I'm just getting into coding, so this may not be the most efficient way of doing it, but this is how I did it:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO HELLO
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
color 01
ECHO HELLO
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
color 02
ECHO HELLO
```

and so one and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple way of doing such and made it simple as possible.
At the "pause" at the end is where you would continue your code.
[Picture of executed Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqewe.png)

```
# [CODE]        [DESCRIPTION]
#
# echo. &       starts a new line
# echo.         skips a line
# PainText 08       08 is color code for gray   Type "color ?" for color codes
# " Red"        The space befor text gives space between the word befor it


@echo off
cls && color 08

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (set "DEL=%%a")


<nul set /p=""
call :PainText 08 "Gray"
call :PainText 04 " Red"
call :PainText 02 " Green"
call :PainText 08 " Gray"
echo. &
call :PainText 02 "Line 2 Green No space"
echo. &
echo.
call :PainText 01 "H"
call :PainText 02 "E"
call :PainText 03 "L"
call :PainText 03 "L"
call :PainText 05 "O"
echo.


goto :end

:PainText
<nul set /p "=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "+" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul
goto :eof

:end
echo.

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo off & cls
set NUM=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
for %%y in (%NUM%) do ( 
    for %%x in (%NUM%) do (
        color %%y%%x & for /l %%A in (1,1,200) do (dir /s)
        timeout 1 >nul
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Since an answer was already accepted, include some info about why your answer is better

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, I was inspired by John Kens' answer to I write a modified version below that can be called from another batch file, like this:

```
rem Put this in your favourite batch file.
call output-coloured-message 02 "SUCCESS!"
```

Call it from the command prompt with no arguments to get USAGE, to remind you how to use it.

```
@echo off

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------
rem File Name: output-coloured-message.bat
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (set "DEL=%%a")

<nul set /p=""

if "%1"=="" goto :usage

call :PainText %1 %2

goto :end

:PainText
<nul set /p "=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "+" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul
goto :eof

:usage
@echo.
@echo USAGE: %~n0 xx "My Message"
@echo.
@echo   Examples:
@echo.
@echo   %~n0 04 "We ran into a problem."
call :PainText 04 "  We ran into a problem."
@echo.
@echo   %~n0 02 "SUCCESS!"
call :PainText 02 "  SUCCESS!"
@echo.
@echo.
@echo   type color ? for a list of colours.
@echo   type colour to restore the default.
goto :end

:end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo off & cls
title   never buy these they're so easy to make... hmu for source code             

    -%pinging:IP%-
color 0D

echo =================================================================
echo i flex on my unhittable ovh, you flex on an easy to hit trash ovh
echo =================================================================
set /p IP=Enter IP:
:top
title :: this skid's boutta get slammed FeelsGoodMan ::    -%pinging:IP%-
PING -n 1 %IP% | FIND "TTL="
IF ERRORLEVEL (echo stop flexing on ovh's i down them with ease, mine on the other hand is unhittable.):
set /a num=(%Random%%%9)+1
color %num%IP   ping -t 2 0 10 127.0.0.1 >nul
GoTo top
```

This is an ip pinging that has custom timed out messages for if something such as a website or server is down, also, can use for if booting people offline, I can make a tool that opens files and individual pingers dependant on your input, and a built in geo-location tool.

Answer (score -3):

Try this command:

```
@echo off
cls
:loop
echo RAINBOW
color 0
echo RAINBOW
color 1
echo RAINBOW
color 2
echo RAINBOW
color 3
echo RAINBOW
color 4
echo RAINBOW
color 5
echo RAINBOW
color 6
echo RAINBOW
color 8
echo RAINBOW
color 9
echo RAINBOW
color A
echo RAINBOW
color B
echo RAINBOW
color C
echo RAINBOW
color D
echo RAINBOW
color E
echo RAINBOW
goto loop
```

This should create color changing text go in a loop.
Edit: You can change the words rainbow to whatever you want.

Answer (score -4):

on particular computer color codes can be assigned to different RGB color by editing color values in cmd window properties. Easy click color on color palete and change their rgb values.